# How to wait for tag before a git checkout?

Tags: git

I have created the following bash functions:

```sh
function wait_for_tag() {
  tag=v${1#v}
  interval=${2:-20}
    while :; do

        echo "Waiting for tag ${tag}..."
        git remote update > /dev/null 2>&1
        git rev-parse --verify --quiet "${tag}" && break
        sleep ${interval}
    done
}

function git_checkout() {
  tag=v${1#v}
    is_release && wait_for_tag "${tag}"
    git checkout ${tag} || echo "testing"
    npm install
}
```

I expect when I do `git_checkout v2.0.13-bs-redux-saga-router-dom-intl` to checkout the tag if it is already existing, otherwise, to fetch for new tags and try again later.

This seems to work nice in a local environment, but when I do that in Gitlab-CI, the parallel pipelines are never seeing the new tag, even if they are tagged and existing on Gitlab UI.

How can I ensure that the `wait_for_tag` function does really retrieve tags and why does `git remote update` fail to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: try `git fetch --tags`.

---

First, `git remote update` just runs `git fetch`, more or less.  The only special thing is that if you have multiple remotes—`origin`, `upstream`, and so on—it runs *more than one* `git fetch`.  The particular set of remotes that get fetched is configurable, so if your CI system configures its Git, you'll need to see what configuration it has set.  (If you have only one remote, `origin`, `git remote update` is likely set up to fetch from that one remote, as any other setup would be almost crazy.)

Meanwhile, `git fetch remote` obtains new commits and references from the named *`remote`*.  The particular *set* of references used, which affects which commits get picked up and which if any tags get picked up, is configurable.  So if your CI system configures its Git, you'll need to see what configuration it has set.  If it's using shallow and/or single-branch clones, it may never obtain the tag.

Alternatively, you can use a `git fetch` command with a refspec:

```
git fetch origin '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'
```

or:

```
git fetch origin +refs/tags/$tag:refs/tags/$tag
```

to force it to attempt to get the one specific tag.  The `+` here means *overwrite my current, existing tag of the same name, if it exists*, so if you do not want that to happen, leave it out.

Finally, note that `git fetch --tags` has the same effect as *adding* `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` to your fetch.  This is not quite the same as *writing*:

```
git fetch origin 'refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'
```

as this last variant (with explicit refspec) overrides the implied refspec.  (Explaining this last sentence is beyond the scope of this answer.)

Note that this variant *does not* use a leading `+`.  But in the end:

```
git fetch --tags
```

may be the simplest and easiest method.

Comment: Let's make sure I understand you totally please. Are you saying that `git remote update` should update the tags with a `git clone https://github.com/mynamspace/project.git` automatically and you don't know why it does not work? Switching to `git fetch +refs...` SHOULD not solve my issue but it MAY?

Comment: How can I ensure the choice of the right action to do? I could cat `.git/config` to get more details of the CI git clone.

Comment: Essentially, without knowing precisely *how* your CI did *its* `git clone`, I can't answer the question. I can only provide general guidelines. Viewing the config file (on the CI system) would answer some questions; checking for the existence of `.git/shallow` would answer the other important one.

Comment: This is how we did clone: `git clone https://gitlab.myorg.com/mynamespace/myorg`. I will look for the `.git/*` and inform you. I have tried also with `git fetch` but it does not work.

Comment: `Waiting for tag v2.0.16...
8e4341fa9a71299e03fd9e38df9f530a5247bff7  tag 'v2.0.16' of https://module.gitlab-us.com/tools/rollup-umd
ref: refs/heads/master
[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
 url = https://module.gitlab-us.com/tools/rollup-umd.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/master`

Comment: I have tried with `git fetch origin +refs/tags/${tag}:refs/tags/${tag} || echo "${tag} is not existing"`  and the job is crashing for some unknown reason `14cc03a8d9ebccec0f78412d995ea0b16538fd2ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
`

Comment: Hm, hard to read the output without newlines but it looks normal (not single-branch, not shallow clone). The last line you quoted above has a hash ID in it, followed immediately by the word `ERROR` (`14cc03a8d9ebccec0f78412d995ea0b16538fd2ERROR`), so it looks as though you *are* getting the tag and then the script is terminating, with the CI system claiming this means the whole thing failed.

Comment: Yes, I have changed my function to `echo "Waiting for tag ${tag}..."
  git fetch --tags --quiet
  git rev-parse --verify --quiet "${tag}" && break
  sleep ${interval}` and it seems to catch the tags, that strange, `git fetch --all` doesn't catch it

Comment: `git fetch --all` means fetch from *all remotes*, not all references. `--tags` tells fetch to (in effect) add `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` to the refspec set. Without this, Git defaults to adding any tags that point to any commits that fetch brings in, plus some cases of historical tags that match commits Git already has (the exact details are hard to pin down as this code in Git has been changed many times and is version-dependent). The short version is that without an explicit tag refspec or `--tags` you might not get the tag you want.

Comment: `git fetch --tags` was the only working option thanks.